# SSH login takes 15 seconds

Tags: ssh, login, windows-subsystem-for-linux, timeout

SSH login takes 15 seconds

I got two devices:

- WSL for Windows  running: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL
  1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
- Raspbian running: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

And a centos 8 server.

The first one (WSL), takes 15 seconds to login to the server, either by password or public key.
Raspbian is inmediate.
I use the ip to connect from both devices.

I've set the server's ssh daemon log to debug3 and I could not see much difference between the 2 logins, I see though the 15 seconds delay here:

```
Oct 17 09:13:20 localhost sshd[2080]: debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password" [preauth]
Oct 17 09:13:20 localhost sshd[2080]: debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
Oct 17 09:13:20 localhost sshd[1979]: debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 50867
Oct 17 09:13:36 localhost sshd[2080]: debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
Oct 17 09:13:36 localhost sshd[2080]: debug1: userauth-request for user marco service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
```

Any clues at what should I be looking for?

This is the ssh -vvv output, I've added timestamp

```
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
[2021-10-21 19:53:13] debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
[2021-10-21 19:53:22] debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
[2021-10-21 19:53:22] No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[2021-10-21 19:53:22] 
[2021-10-21 19:53:22] 
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] 
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] 
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug1: Offering public key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[2021-10-21 19:53:33] debug3: send packet: type 50
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: receive packet: type 51
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Trying private key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_dsa
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: no such identity: /home/marco/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Trying private key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ecdsa
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: no such identity: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Trying private key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: no such identity: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Trying private key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ed25519
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: no such identity: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Trying private key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: no such identity: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Trying private key: /home/marco/.ssh/id_xmss
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: no such identity: /home/marco/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: authmethod_lookup password
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
[2021-10-21 19:53:34] debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Not sure what's going on there, but see what `ssh -vvv ...` shows on the client side on Ubuntu/WSL.  (Add the output to your question).  Thanks!

Comment: Done! I will need to check that kerberos issue, looks like its causing the delay/rejection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable GSSAPIAuthentication. Edit the `sshd_config` file in the WSL and change `GSSAPIAuthentication` from `yes` to `no`.

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Save the changes and restart the SSH daemon.

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

**Source:** [Techglimpse](https://techglimpse.com/ssh-connection-takes-long-time-delay/)